# requestFocus not changing the focus when when using getCurrentFocus

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am making an OTP `Activity` and need to implement delete feature, I have the below function that should be fired `onKey` up of the backspace button. My thought is that I could use `getCurrentFocus` to know which fields are currently being filled and then use `requestFocus` to select the one before, but it does not seem to work, I have another function for `goToNext` that works just fine, so I am confused why.

[image]

```
 public void goToPrevious() {
    EditText currentFocus = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();


    if (currentFocus == otpOne) {
        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpTwo) {
        otpOne.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpThree) {
        otpTwo.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpFour) {
        otpThree.requestFocus();

        return;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for `goToNext` that works fine.

```
public void goToNext() {
    EditText currentFocus = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();

    if (currentFocus == otpOne) {
        otpTwo.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpTwo) {
        otpThree.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpThree) {
        otpFour.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpFour) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I call the goToPrevious by implementing an onKeyListener, below is the code

```
 @Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    EditText currentFocus = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
    Log.i("ENOUGH", "onKey: " + keyCode + " " + event.getAction() + " " + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL: {
            currentFocus.setText(null);
            goToPrevious();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How did you call this methods?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH The activity implements OnKeyListener, which I use for all the form fields, I have updated the question with the code on the overriden OnKey methdo

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH I was originally using the TextWatcher, but I could not get the pressed key from that, so I had to start moving to onKeyListener, the goToNext still uses the TextWatcher

Answer (score 1):

I got to fix it by passing the value of `getCurrentFocus` directly into `goToPrevious` for some very weird reason the value of `getCurrentFocus` inside the `onKey` handler is different from `goToPrevious`, below is the code I ended up with.

```
public void goToNext(EditText currentFocus) {

    if (currentFocus == otpOne) {
        otpTwo.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpTwo) {
        otpThree.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpThree) {
        otpFour.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpFour) {
        return;
    }
}

public void goToPrevious(EditText currentFocus) {

    if (currentFocus == otpOne) {
        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpTwo) {
        otpOne.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpThree) {
        otpTwo.requestFocus();

        return;
    }

    if (currentFocus == otpFour) {
        otpThree.requestFocus();

        return;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("ENOUGH", "onKey: " + keyCode + " " + event.getAction() + " " + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        EditText currentFocus = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL: {
                if (currentFocus.getText().length() > 0) {
                    currentFocus.setText(null);
                } else {
                    goToPrevious(currentFocus);

                    EditText focused = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
                    focused.setText(null);
                }

                return false;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD:
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                return true;
            default: {
                currentFocus.setText("");
                goToNext(currentFocus);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this following:

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(s.length()==1)
                    {
                        et2.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(s.length()==0)
                    {
                        et1.clearFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

            et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(s.length()==1)
                    {
                        et3.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(s.length()==0)
                    {
                        et1.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

            et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(s.length()==1)
                    {
                        et4.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(s.length()==0)
                    {
                        et2.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

            et4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(s.length()==1)
                    {
                        et5.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(s.length()==0)
                    {
                        et3.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

            et5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(s.length()==1)
                    {
                        et6.requestFocus();
                    }
                    else if(s.length()==0)
                    {
                        et4.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

            et6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(s.length()==1)
                    {
                        et6.clearFocus();
                    }
                    else if(s.length()==0)
                    {
                        et5.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });
```